# Fetch one JSON object and use it reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm very new to JS and ReactJS and I try to fetch an endpoint which gives me a JSON Object like this :

```
{"IDPRODUCT":4317892,"DESCRIPTION":"Some product of the store"}
```

I get this JSON Object by this endpoint :

```
http://localhost:3000/product/4317892
```

But I dont how to use it in my react application, I want to use those datas to display them on the page

My current code looks like this but it's not working and I'm sure not good too :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Products extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: {}
        };
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/product/4317892')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    res
                })
            })
            .catch((error => {
                console.error(error);
            }));
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        const { postItems } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {postItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Products;
```

In the console.log(this.state) there is the data, but I'm so confused right now, dont know what to do

Since I'm here, I have one more question, I want to have an input in my App.js where the user will be able to type the product's id and get one, how can I manage to do that ? Passing the data from App.js to Products.js which is going to get the data and display them

Thank you all in advance

Comment: You initialize the `state` with `posts` as a property. Then you `setState` a property named `res`. Finally in `render` you destructure the `state` and try to extract a property named `postItems`. So which one is it the correct name ? Please post exactly what is logged from `console.log(this.state)`

Comment: I did correct it thanks to the @Gilsdav answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state doesn't have a `postItems` property which is considered `undefined` and react therefore would not render. In your situation there is no need to define a new `const` and use the state directly.

Also, when you `setState()`, you need to tell it which state property it should set the value to.

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/product/4317892')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state, // Not required but just a heads up on using mutation
                posts: res
            })
        })
        .catch((error => {
            console.error(error);
        }));
}


render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
        <div>
            <p><strong>Id: {this.state.posts.IDPRODUCT}</strong></p>
            <p>Description: {this.state.posts.DESCRIPTION}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: no need for `...this.state` because `setState` does partial updates (*it merges the objects*). Spreading the previous state is required only if you do deep nested updates and you only need to do it for the parent objects/arrays of the part you are updating, not for the whole state.

Answer (score 0):

I have got 3 names for the same thing in your js: posts, postItems and res.
React can not determine for you that posts = postItems = res.
So make changes like this:

-

```
this.state = {
    postItems: {}
};
```

-

```
this.setState({
    postItems: res
});
```

-

```
return (
    <div>
        {JSON.stringify(postItems)}
        <div>
            <span>{postItems.IDPRODUCT}</span>
            <span>{postItems.DESCRIPTION}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I can now have the json in the div, but now how I can parse this json into different components like paragraphs or divs ?

Comment: @oskll I had updated the answer with an example. You just have to use `{}` syntax to show element into your HTML

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try that !

Answer (score -1):

```
{postItems["IDPRODUCT"]}
```

Will display the first value. You can do the same for the other value. Alternatively, you can put

```
{JSON.stringify(postItems)}
```

With respect to taking input in the App to use in this component, you can pass that input down through the props and access it in this component via this.props.myInput. In your app it'll look like this:

```
<Products myInput={someInput} />
```